# How do I download images using the Scryfall API and Python

Tags: python, json, api

Pretty new to APIs and Python for that matter. I am need to grab images from Scryfall using their API. Here is the link to the API documentation. https://scryfall.com/docs/api

They are using json and the code looks like this. (https://api.scryfall.com/cards/cn2/78?format=json&pretty=true)

This is the part that contains the URIs to the images.

```
 "image_uris": {
    "small": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/small/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "normal": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/normal/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "large": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/large/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "png": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/png/en/cn2/78.png?1517813031",
    "art_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/art_crop/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "border_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/border_crop/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031"
  },
```

How would I grab the images at those URIs and download them?

I found this on github but I'm not really sure where to begin with it.
https://github.com/NandaScott/Scrython

I am using the "Default Cards" file on this page
https://scryfall.com/docs/api/bulk-data

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the image data and save it locally. Step 1, getting the image data using Python:

```
import requests as req

img_uris = {
    "small": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/small/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "normal": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/normal/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "large": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/large/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "png": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/png/en/cn2/78.png?1517813031",
    "art_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/art_crop/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031",
    "border_crop": "https://img.scryfall.com/cards/border_crop/en/cn2/78.jpg?1517813031"
}

img_request = req.get(img_uris['normal'])
# Always test your response obj before performing any work!
img_request.raise_for_status()
```

The function `raise_for_status()` will raise whatever exception `requests` had while making the request. If nothing happens, that means we received a 200 response code indicating our request was good! Now step 2, saving the data:

```
import os
img_file = "queen_marchesa_norm.jpg"

with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), img_file), 'w') as f:
    f.write(img_request.content)
```

Here we declare a filename, use that filename to make a writeable file object, and then write all the data from our `img_request` to our file object. If you want to learn more about `requests` check the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#quickstart).

Comment: I assume that since that since I want to grab all of the "normal" images from the entire json I would need to build a loop to do that and save the results to a list and then loope through the list and download the images?

Comment: I think I need to import the json into Python too right?